# pkill and killall command is not working on Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following process:

```
root     18538     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:36 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
root     18541     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:32 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
root     18544     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:36 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
root     18545     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:37 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
root     18546     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:36 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
root     18547     1  0 00:03 ?        00:00:40 /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python /data/software/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/gunicorn zapier2cloud.wsgi:application -c ./zapier2cloud.conf.py
```

I ran the command: `sudo pkill -f gunicorn`, but after that, it still shows the same processes with the same pids.

What happened? is there any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes processes can just ignored your kill command. Default signal sent is SIGTERM, if it is not caught, your process will continue to run.

To force kill your process, send a SIGKILL signal using '-9' :

```
kill -9 {PID}
```

List of signals :

```
kill -l
```

Comment: `killall -9 gunicorn`, oh this command is working.